# Android studio animation file

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create a frame by frame animation in android studio and can not figure out how to do it. I know how to do it in eclipse but in android studio there is no "new android xml file" with support for creating animation files. I have tried adding an XML file to the drawable folder and it moves it to the layouts folder. I have tried to code an animation-list but android studio acts like it does not exist. I can't seem to find anything online to help me. I have looked at developer.android.com which is helpful if your trying to figure out the code, but it does not help you with all the bits before that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the project pane (defaults on the left side of the screen), make sure you are in the project view. If the upper left corner of the pane days "android" and has a robot icon, click it and select "project". Now click and select the "res" folder in the main source set tree. Right click on it and go to new -> android resource file. It should pop up a new dialog where you can name it, select what type (look for animation, animator or drawable animation), and even add qualifiers. Click done once you have set it up and your new file should be in the expected place.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hopefully this post helps somebody else. Even the book i bought that works with Android Studio specifically didn't even mention that feature. Now that i know about it, its pretty slick.

Comment: You are very welcome, glad you were able to get past the issue!

Comment: Thanks. But you don't have to be in `project` view.

Answer (score 5):

You should right click on "res" or "anim",not on the project name,then you can choose "new android xml file".By the way, you should put animation files in "anim" or "animation" folder.

Comment: I ended up finding the "anim"/"animation" folder on accident. Does it matter which folder name you use? By accident i mean looking through the new item options. The anim / animation folder is not created by default.

Comment: I use intellij. Intellij create an "anim" folder when I create my first animation file and put the file in it by default.It's recommended to put different xml file in a corresponding folder.